# Getting DOM element properties in Angular

Tags: angular

It is my understanding that it is bad practice in Angular to interact with DOM elements directly and that [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) should be used instead. I have noticed however that Renderer2 is full of setter methods (setStyle, setProperty, setValue, etc..), but there are no getter methods. How should one obtain DOM element properties without interacting with the element directly, i.e `elementRef.nativeElement.<propertyOfInterest>`?

Example:

- Get `scrollTop` value of Element: `elementRef.nativeElement.scrollTop`
- Set `scrollTop` value of Element: `renderer.setProperty(elementRef.nativeElement, 'scrollTop', myValue)`

If this is the only way to get element property values, then why does that not defeat the purpose of Renderer2?

Reference Material:

- [angular.io - Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2)
- [alligator.io - Using Renderer2 in Angular](https://alligator.io/angular/using-renderer2/)

Comment: hm, maybe Renderer2 really focuses on rendering like "generating HTML based on input data"?

Comment: The point of using Renderer2 is to avoid interacting with the DOM because it makes your app dependent on the DOM, which makes it non-functional outside of a browser (i.e. server-side rendering, native, etc.). If your app only interacts with the DOM due to user actions, you at least don't have to worry about breaking server-side rendering, and I believe there's a property you can check called isBrowser that's part of the @angular/universal module you can use to make sure you don't interact with the DOM when it's not available.